# How to solve Run-Time Error '429 : Activex component can't create object' in VB6?

Tags: image, vb6, activex, runtime-error

I ve seen a lot of questions about this but still couldnt find a solution for my code.
I had this problem in VB6 while debugging..

```
Set img = New ImageFile
img.LoadFile mainform.picturePath & stock & ".jpg"
```

seems like i cannot create a new `ImageFile` and getting this crazy error report.

I tried more than several dll registering.

I also tried updating DirectX to 9.0c and re installed vb6 - office components..

But still getting the error. I dont know what could be causing that.

Comment: As an experiment, replace `New ImageFile` with `CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")` and give it a try. Also, if your PC is XP SP1, have you tried reinstalling WIA (maybe via http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18287 )?

Comment: What is `ImageFile`? Where's it defined and in what library?

Comment: @rskar Yea you rule. I ve tried reinstalling WIA. Its wierd before reinstalling vb6 i tried this actually but didnt work but now works just fine. I guess i didnt follow the steps carefully. Post it as an answer.. xD also CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile") is really usefull too. I must admit this was a quick problem solving i dont really ask everything here.. First i try my best to findout by my self and today this issue took my 4 hours so thanks really much.

Comment: For reference, the `ImageFile` object is nothing to do with ADO.

Comment: @Deanna yea i know my mistake but i also had that library too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure your reference is correct here. ADO does not have an ImageFile type.

I think what you want is the [Windows Image Acquisition Automation Library](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18287)

After installing you can update your references in the VB project and should be able to correctly create an instance of an ImageType.

Comment: I had Windows Image Acquisition Automation Library already but the real problem was about reinstalling the WIA (microsoft.com/download/en/… ) thanks to @rskar solved this issue.